# Why is REDIRECT header_check creating a CC

Tags: postfix, redirect

I configured Postfix with a custom before-queue filter script (fuglu) which inspects every incoming email first, and then adds the following header:

```
X-Fuglu-Test: Test Email
```

In postfix, I configured a header check to redirect email matching header above as follows:

```
/^X-Fuglu-Test:\sTest\sEmail/ REDIRECT testuser@myemailcomp.com
```

A test email sent to `postfixin@mta.myinternalhost.com` on the MTA was successfully redirected to `testuser@myemailcomp.com`, a user on a different MTA.

However, Postfix CC'd `postfixin@mta.myinternalhost.com`, the original recipient, as part of the redirect.

What I've observed is that Postfix sends the CC along with the REDIRECT to the nearest relay MTA. That MTA delivers to `testuser@myemailcomp.com` as expected, but also routes the email back to `postfixin@myinternalhost.com` to encounter the filter again, which in turn REDIRECTs to `testuser@myemailcomp.com`, ad infinitum.

Any way to prevent Postfix from doing a CC during a header_check REDIRECT?

Here's what my `/var/log/maillog` looks like:

```
Jul 28 20:50:39 mta postfix/smtpd[4501]: connect from unknown[10.102.252.61]
Jul 28 20:50:39 mta postfix/smtpd[4504]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 28 20:50:39 mta postfix/smtpd[4501]: NOQUEUE: client=unknown[10.102.252.61]
Jul 28 20:50:39 mta postfix/smtpd[4504]: A520EA0437: client=unknown[10.102.252.61]
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/smtpd[4506]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/smtpd[4501]: NOQUEUE: client=unknown[10.102.252.61]
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/smtpd[4506]: 65C63A0446: client=unknown[10.102.252.61]
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/cleanup[4507]: 65C63A0446: **redirect**: header X-Fuglu-Test: Test Email from unknown[10.102.252.61]; from=<testuser@internal.com> to=<postfixin@mta.myinternalhost.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<sc-l-johnny.internal.com>: testuser@myemailcomp.com
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/cleanup[4507]: 65C63A0446: message-id=<>
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/qmgr[4281]: 65C63A0446: from=<testuser@internal.com>, size=1166, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/smtpd[4506]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/smtpd[4501]: disconnect from unknown[10.102.252.61]
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/smtp[4508]: 65C63A0446: to=<testuser@myemailcomp.com>, orig_to=<postfixin@mta.myinternalhost.com>, relay=smtp-relay.internal.com[10.120.3.100]:25, delay=0.23, delays=0.19/0.01/0.01/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 u6T3oe96012173 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul 28 20:50:40 mta postfix/qmgr[4281]: 65C63A0446: removed
Jul 28 20:50:44 mta postfix/smtpd[4501]: connect from microsoftrelay.internal.com[10.120.10.142]
```